# manコマンドの「オンラインのマニュアルページをフォーマットして表示します」とはどういう意味ですか？

Tags: linux, unix, man

manコマンドの「オンラインのマニュアルページをフォーマットして表示します」とはどういう意味ですか？

ネットワークが繋がっていない状態（オフライン）でも `$ man man` や `$ man ls` でマニュアルを参照できています。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

「オンライン」という言葉はネットワークに繋がっている状態以外に、単にデジタル化された状態を指すことがあります。

また、Unixシステムのマニュアルに関しては、マニュアルのデータが入っている `/usr/share` ディレクトリをマシン間で共有する運用も昔はよくありました。

[Weblio 「オンラインマニュアル」](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%82%AA%E3%83%B3%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%83%9E%E3%83%8B%E3%83%A5%E3%82%A2%E3%83%AB)

Comment: オンラインの意味が「ネットワークにつながっている」意味以外に使われている例って見たことない気がするのですが、一般的なのでしょうか？

Comment: 「オンラインヘルプ」「オンラインマニュアル」といったマニュアルやヘルプといった場面だけ、デジタル化された意味合いをもつという特殊な使い方なのでしょうか。

Comment: RAID なんかだと「オンラインスワップ」とか「オンラインスペア」とかいう用語も使いますし、単純に「線がつながっている」という意味でしょう。ハードディスクに線がつながっている状態で読めるマニュアルってことで。

Comment: @shingo.nakanishi 回答に int32_t さんが含めたリンク先では次のように言及されています、「製本されたマニュアルなどの代わりに、PCの画面上に表示する機能やサービス」/ 今回の文脈では "オンライン = デジタル化された" くらいの意味合いなのかなと私は理解しました。

Comment: いやむしろ「電源線がつながっているとき」転じて「電源ONで」読めるマニュアルってことで。オフラインとはこの例では「紙」のことですね。結果的に「デジタル化された」の意味で問題ないっす。

Comment: なるほど。たしかに製本との対比で説明されているので、「紙」との対比とみると良さそうですね